# Python: Convert a list of dictionary into a table

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this list of sub dictionaries:

```
my_dict = [ {'type' : 'type_1', 'prob' : 2, 'x_sum' : 3, 'y_sum' : 5}
 {'type' : 'type_2', 'prob' : 3, 'x_sum' : 8, 'y_sum' : 6}]
```

I want a print it as a table:

```
type  |prob|x_sum|y_sum
type_1|2   |3    |5
type_2|3   |8    |6
```

I tried this solution :

```
for row in zip(*([key] + value for key, value in sorted(my_dict.items()))):
print(*row)
```

but got error: 
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
How I can fix the list problem?

Comment: `list` doesn't have `items()` method

Comment: You have a list of dictionaries, and list doesn't have items method(), you need iterate over all the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest is to use Pandas as described [Convert list of Dictionaries to Dataframe](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-list-of-dicts/)

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict = [ {'type' : 'type_1', 'prob' : 2, 'x_sum' : 3, 'y_sum' : 5},
 {'type' : 'type_2', 'prob' : 3, 'x_sum' : 8, 'y_sum' : 6}]

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
     type  prob  x_sum  y_sum
0  type_1     2      3      5
1  type_2     3      8      6
```

**Without Index Column**

```
df_no_indices = df.to_string(index=False)
print(df_no_indices)
```

**Output**

```
  type  prob  x_sum  y_sum
 type_1     2      3      5
 type_2     3      8      6
```

**Other Format Examples**

[Source](https://towardsdatascience.com/pretty-displaying-tricks-for-columnar-data-in-python-2fe3b3ed9b83)

*PostSQL*

```
from tabulate import tabulate
pdtabulate=lambda df:tabulate(df,headers='keys',tablefmt='psql')
print(pdtabulate(df))

+----+--------+--------+---------+---------+
|    | type   |   prob |   x_sum |   y_sum |
|----+--------+--------+---------+---------|
|  0 | type_1 |      2 |       3 |       5 |
|  1 | type_2 |      3 |       8 |       6 |
+----+--------+--------+---------+---------+
```

*HTML*

```
pdtabulate=lambda df:tabulate(df,headers='keys',tablefmt='html')
print(pdtabulate(df))
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th style="text-align: right;">  </th><th>type  </th><th style="text-align: right;">  prob</th><th style="text-align: right;">  x_sum</th><th style="text-align: right;">  y_sum</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;"> 0</td><td>type_1</td><td style="text-align: right;">     2</td><td style="text-align: right;">      3</td><td style="text-align: right;">      5</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;"> 1</td><td>type_2</td><td style="text-align: right;">     3</td><td style="text-align: right;">      8</td><td style="text-align: right;">      6</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't you think installing pandas for such a simple task is a little overkill?

Comment: @franvergara66--maybe not, but since Pandas is so useful I would think a lot of users would have it installed or should look into it even they have not used it before since it makes problems like this trivial.  Trivial since Pandas provides a single line including formatting the table output.  Compare this to non-Pandas solutions.

Comment: Thanks! Both answers helped :) Table I get in pandas looks more clean. However, I agree with not to install extra packages when it is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

you can use:

```
from collections import defaultdict

r = defaultdict(list)
for d in my_dict:
    for k, v in d.items():
        r[k].append(v)

print('|'.join((e.ljust(7) for e in d.keys())))

print('\n'.join(('|'.join(str(e).ljust(7) for e in t) for t in zip(*r.values()) )))
```

output:

```
type   |prob   |x_sum  |y_sum  
type_1 |2      |3      |5      
type_2 |3      |8      |6
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am wondering what is the best and professional way to do this because using pandas is easier and the output is more clean .

Comment: It depends on what you need, if you jus need for your debugging, making a function with my code will be more clean since you do not have to install pandas, if you already have installed pandas than you  can use pandas solution